# model.fit(),ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: python, deep-learning, model, conv-neural-network

I'm making a CNN model using a pre-trained model to extract the features, and I'm facing an error when I do model.fit()

Here is the full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import glob
import pickle
import joblib
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
from sklearn import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy as np
import glob
import keras
from keras.models       import Model
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
from keras.models import Model
import glob
from keras.utils import np_utils


imgs=[]
final_output_84_84=[]
lables=[]
for filefilepath in glob.iglob('/content/drive/MyDrive/Densenet/*'):
    
    
    if filefilepath[-1] == 'g':
        
        img = cv2.imread(filefilepath)
        imgs_colored=cv2.imread(filefilepath)
        imgs_colored=cv2.resize(imgs_colored,(512,512))
        #imgs_colored.append(img)

        print(filefilepath)
        #print(filefilepath[19:-6])
        #print(filefilepath[-5])
        split = filefilepath.split(".")
        #print(split)
        print(split[0][32:])
        print(split[1])

        label=split[0][32:]
        example_number = split[1]
        imgs.append([imgs_colored,(label)])
        #final_output_84_84.append(imgs_colored)
        #lables.append(int(label))
    
import random

random.shuffle(imgs)

for i,j in imgs:
        final_output_84_84.append(i)
        lables.append(j)
    
print(len(final_output_84_84))
print(len(lables))

img_size=(512,512)

from tensorflow import keras 
y=keras.utils.to_categorical(lables, num_classes=5, dtype='float32')
final_output_84_84 = np.array(final_output_84_84,dtype="float16")/255

from keras.models       import Model
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.applications.inception_resnet_v2 import InceptionResNetV2
from keras.applications.xception import Xception

original_model = DenseNet201(include_top=False, input_shape=(512,512,3))

transfer_layer = original_model.get_layer('relu')
bottleneck_model  = Model(inputs=original_model.input,outputs=transfer_layer.output)

test = final_output_84_84[0]
test = test.reshape(1, img_size[0], img_size[1],3)
test_shape = bottleneck_model.predict(test).shape
print(test_shape)
shape = (final_output_84_84.shape[0],test_shape[1],test_shape[2],test_shape[3])
print(shape)
print(shape[1:])

bottelneck_features = []
for i in final_output_84_84:
    
    i = i.reshape(1, img_size[0], img_size[1],3)
    bottelneck_features.append(bottleneck_model.predict(i))
    print(len(bottelneck_features))

    
bottelneck_features=np.array(bottelneck_features)
print(bottelneck_features.shape)

bottelneck_features =  bottelneck_features.reshape(shape)
print(bottelneck_features.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import svm

(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(final_output_84_84, lables,test_size=0.05, random_state=1250)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten,Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf

model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(final_output_84_84.shape[1:])))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))



model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

history=model.fit(X_train,np.array(y_train), batch_size=32, epochs=30, shuffle=True,validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

the error log:

```
Epoch 1/30
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-e4eb897305f7> in <module>()
----> 1 history=model.fit(X_train,np.array(y_train), batch_size=32, epochs=30, shuffle=True,validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1790, in categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5083, in categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible
```

I will appreciate your help, also I'm still a beginner, and I'm doing this for my graduation project, so I will appreciate your fast response.

------- --------------- ------------ ------------ ---------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------ --------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ------------ ----------- --------- ---------- -------- -

Answer (score 1):

You change your labels to one-hot encoded labels, and call that variable y here:

> y = keras.utils.to_categorical(lables, num_classes=5, dtype='float32')

But then you use the labels(lables) variable when using the train_test_split function here:

> (X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test) =
> train_test_split(final_output_84_84, lables,test_size=0.05,
> random_state=1250)

You should use the one-hot encoded labels in the latter.